# Expectation of a joint distribution or RVs X Y Z

Tags: probability

How does E[XYZ] breakdown for correlated discrete RVs X Y and Z (or more than two, at least)? Is there a link to a full example somewhere?

What I see is that E[XYZ] = SumX[SumY[SumZ [ (XYZ) (jpmf of XYZ) ]]]

Most examples i see assume specific values of the jpmf. But is there a way to expand this in general terms if don't know the jpmf of XYZ?
I am trying to understand moments of multiple RVs and their higher order moments.

Thank you

Comment: you need to know the joint probability mass function or conditional probability mass functions that will allow you to get the pmf of $X,Y,Z$.

Comment: [Law of the unconscious statistician](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician): $$ \mathrm{E}\left(f(X,Y,Z)\right) = \sum_{x,y,z} f(x,y,z) \mathbb{P}\left(X=x,Y=y,Z=z\right)$$

Comment: Did you mean the triple $(X,Y,Z)$ or the product $XYZ$?

Comment: I mean the expectation of the product of RVs X, Y, Z: E[XYZ]